# Вопрос про table

Tags: css, вёрстка

Игнорируется **в Google Chrome** `width: 200px;` например для первой колонки, хоть оно там и прописано:

http://jsfiddle.net/5mHBM/3/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column {
  background: #e3e9ee;
  border-left: 1px solid #eff2f5;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
  text-align: left;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column div {
  color: #51677a;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 13px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column:first-child {
  border-left: none !important;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column:last-child {
  border-right: none !important;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_content {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_url {
  width: 200px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_author {
  width: 150px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_date {
  width: 120px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_control {
  width: 100px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_content {
  border-top: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="admin_tasks_blacklist_table">
  <tr>
    <td class="column column_url">
      <div>Ссылка</div>
    </td>
    <td class="column column_author">
      <div>Отправитель</div>
    </td>
    <td class="column column_date">
      <div>Время</div>
    </td>
    <td class="column column_control">
      <div>Управление</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column_content">http://mysite.ru/admin/modules/tasks/blacklist/addddddddddddddddddddddddddddd.php</td>
    <td class="column_content">Руслан Садыхов</td>
    <td class="column_content">сегодня в 13:51</td>
    <td class="column_content">test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Как исправить? `word-wrap: break-word;` тоже не помог :(

Comment: max-width в column_content попробуйте

Comment: @perseidsStarfall, потыкал на Ваших вопросах палец вверх, тем самым поднял карму до 111. В следующий раз в виде ответа оформляйте )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5mHBM/5/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column {
  background: #e3e9ee;
  border-left: 1px solid #eff2f5;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
  text-align: left;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column div {
  color: #51677a;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 13px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column:first-child {
  border-left: none !important;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column:last-child {
  border-right: none !important;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_content {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_url {
  width: 200px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_author {
  width: 150px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_date {
  width: 120px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_control {
  width: 100px;
}
#admin_tasks_blacklist_table .column_content {
  border-top: 1px solid #d3dbe1;
  padding: 8px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="admin_tasks_blacklist_table">
  <tr>
    <td class="column column_url">
      <div>Ссылка</div>
    </td>
    <td class="column column_author">
      <div>Отправитель</div>
    </td>
    <td class="column column_date">
      <div>Время</div>
    </td>
    <td class="column column_control">
      <div>Управление</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column_content">http://mysite.ru/admin/modules/tasks/blacklist/addddddddddddddddddddddddddddd.php</td>
    <td class="column_content">Руслан Садыхов</td>
    <td class="column_content">сегодня в 13:51</td>
    <td class="column_content">test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: меня опередили :)